# Postgres modifying my bcrypt hash, how to make it stop?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, bcrypt

I am hashing my password with bcrypt and trying to store it in Postgres. I don't want to use the native function because I don't want to program any logic like that in Postgres.

Is there someway to escape it or is using the 'text' type not right?

Comment: What is the datatype of the field? Can you share the `insert` and the `create table` SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply store the encrypted password in the database as a plain string. There is no need to use the PostgreSQL functions for encryption. The string should be small enough that you don't need to use a `text` datatype, a `varchar` would be sufficient.

Comment: so when I insert it with 'value($1)', [hash], function(err, res){                                   it won't escape it in any way?"

Comment: it seems to work now. there was a ghost in my machine

Comment: You should use `bytea` not `text` or `varchar`, unless you are using an encoding like base64 for the bcrypt output, as it might not be valid encoded text, may contain null bytes, etc.